# $q doesn't remove pending tasks in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, rootscope

If I create a test for angular where I use `$q` to mock or create a promise then a defer task is created.

I thought that by calling `$rootScope.$apply` should resolve these promises.

But if I do this then call `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()` an exception is thrown because

> Error: Deferred tasks to flush (1): {id: 0, time: 0}

Why is this and how to fix it ?

```
 it.only('should work', function () {
        var spy = sinon.spy();
        $q.when().then(spy);
        $rootScope.$apply();
        spy.should.have.been.called;

        $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
    });
```

Comment: It will if the `$scope` that you are working on is a child of `$rootScope`'s scope.  How are you passing in `$scope` in the test?

Comment: I'm testing a Service. 

The $rootScope is injected in angular.mock. 

`beforeEach('inject dependencies', angular.mock.inject(function ( _$rootScope_){
$rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));`    Thanks  Davin Tryon

Comment: Have you found the solutions for this yet ?